# Okular: set arbitrary number of pages in one row under the overview mode

Tags: pdf, okular

I'm using Ubuntu 18.10 and Okular 1.4.3 to read a book in overview mode, which displays a fixed number of 3 pages in one row:

[image: Okular overview mode]

If I zoom them out, the pages will shrink in place. That is, the number of pages in a row stays unchanged but the padding between them increases:

[image: Zoomed out Okular overview]

I'd like to view more pages in one row but don't find the setting.

Referring to the [official docs](https://web.archive.org/web/20180624105139/https://okular.kde.org/screenshots.php), my desired behavior is demonstrated as a demo, which displays four pages in a row:

[image: Okular showing more previews in each row]

How could I set each row to show an arbitrary number of pages?

I would also appreciate it very much if anyone could introduce a PDF editor which holds such a functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `~/.config/okularpartrc`, add a *PageView* section if it's not there already, and set *ViewColumns* so that it reads:

```
[PageView]
ViewColumns=4
```

I worked this out by inspecting `/usr/share/config.kcfg/okular.kcfg`, after chimak111 on [kubuntuforums.net](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/74797-usr-share-config-kcfg-can-users-modify-any-files-there) discussed it.  One can see from that file that the maximum is 8.  Some other cool settings might be lurking there, like this one.  For some use cases with a big screen, lots of columns like this would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

In more recent versions of Okular (tested with Okular 20.12) this can be easily changed in *Settings* → *Configure Okular* → *General* under *View Options* → *Overview Columns*.